# Using Javascript to Build a Dynamic JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I want the JSON structure to be something like this:

```
var data = [{ "label": "Category A", "value": 20 },
{ "label": "Category B", "value": 50 },
{ "label": "Category C", "value": 30 }];
```

I have a bunch of label and values that can be more than the 3 pairs above (it's dynamic).  The data for each label and value will also be differnt (entered by the user).

How do I create a JSON object like data when a user can enter as many label and value pairs with different data? Thanks,

Comment: `data` is a javascript Array object. Create a new object with your label and use `data.push( your_object )` to append

Comment: just push objects into an array and call `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: so just do obj["label"[ = 'category 1' and push it in to json data? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an array :

```
var ary = [];
```

keep pushing pairs of ( label , value )  that you obtain from some source :

```
ary.push( { "label" :  "a label" , "value" : "a value" } );
```

Once it is done, create the json string as follow:

```
var outputJson = JSON.stringify(ary);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [
  { "label": "Category A", "value": 20 },
  { "label": "Category B", "value": 50 },
  { "label": "Category C", "value": 30 }
];

data.push({ "label": "Category D", "value": 60 });

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
```